# Can a WinForm execute a console program? If so, how?

Tags: .net, command-line

I have a free command line tool called [FW Tools](http://fwtools.maptools.org/). Works great. Here is a sample line i enter in the console window :-

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -a_srs "EPSG:26986" -t_srs "EPSG:4326"
    towns_geodetic.shp TOWNSSURVEY_POLY.shp
```

I wish to change the last to arguments, based on some list i dynamically generate (i use Linq-to-Filesystem and grab all the filenames) and then call this program 'n' times.

I don't care about the output.

Can this be done?

This is all under the .NET environment btw.

#### EDIT

Is there also any way to make sure the code waits for the process to finish?

Comment: See also: [Launching an application (.EXE) from C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240171/launching-an-application-exe-from-c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would take a bit more of a detailed approach to this and do something like this

```
string ApplicationName = "ogr2ogr";
string BaseOptions = "-f \"ESRI Shapefile\" -a_srs \"EPSG:26986\" 
                      -t_srs \"EPSG:4326\"";

//Start your loop here
ProcessStartInfo oStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
oStartInfo.FileName = ApplicationName;
oStartInfo.Arguments = BaseOptions + MyLoopLoadedItemsHere;
Process.Start(oStartInfo)

//If you want to wait for exit, uncomment next line
//oStartInfo.WaitForExit();

//end your loop here
```

Something like this is a bit more readable, at least in my opinion.

Comment: Is this syncronous? So if i loop (where u said start loop / end loop), will it wait for the process to finish (at line Process.Start(..)) before it goes to the next line?

Comment: No, it does not wait for the process to finish, to do that you would need to put in a oStartInfo.WaitForExit(); call after the process.start if you wanted it to wait.

Comment: Finally, is it possible to 'chain' commands in a single 'process' ? currently i have a shortcut that runs a bat file, when i open up this special console window. it contains paths and extra 'prep' crap. Can this be called first (C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /K "C:\Program Files (x86)\FWTools2.3.0\setfw.bat) and then my unique program (ogr2ogr) second ... all in the same 'process'?

Comment: I would just add your individual calls then to the .bat file, and do it all at once.

Answer (score 5):

Use [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx).  Something like ...

```
Process.Start( "cmd /c Gregory -f \"ES RI Shape file\" 
      -a_Sirs \"PEGS:26986\" -t_Sirs \"PEGS:4326\"
      towns_geodetic.Shep TOWNS SURVEY_PLOY.Shep" );
```

[Here are some examples of how to do it a bit cleaner.](http://dotnetperls.com/Content/Process-Start-NET.aspx)

Comment: It's worth noting that Process.Start() can accept all sorts of neat arguments. Pass it a URL and it will open the page using the default web browser. Pass it a mailto: link and it will open a new email message using the default mail client. It's very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Here we go my friend

```
Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\notepad.exe", @"C:\Windows\system.ini");
```

or

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\notepad.exe", 
                                 @"C:\Windows\system.ini");
```