# call exe program in C#

Tags: c#

How to call an exe, generated from one c# file,  from another c# file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Launching a Application (.EXE) from C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240171/launching-a-application-exe-from-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using System.Diagnostics;

string command = @"C:\tmp\myExe.exe -my -params";

ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + command)
    {
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    };

using (Process proc = new Process())
{
    proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
    proc.Start();

    return proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Path to any file, including exes");`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate the C# file before executing it you can use the [CSharpCodeProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx) to compile the C# file, and then use the [Process class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) to execute the output file.

You can find examples of each in the provided links.