# How to call C .exe file from C#?

Tags: c#-4.0, start-process

I have an `.exe` file which was written in C. It is a command line application. I want give command line and also get correspond output in this application through a C# application.

How do I invoke the command and get the output from C#?

Comment: I wonder how many times this question has been asked before. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833171/call-exe-program-in-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) method:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var psi = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = @"c:\work\test.exe",
            Arguments = @"param1 param2",
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        };
        var process = Process.Start(psi);
        if (process.WaitForExit((int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10).TotalMilliseconds))
        {
            var result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [`Process.Start` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

You supply it with the name of your process and any command line arguments and it will run the executable.

You can capture any output which you can then process in your C# application.