# How to add a Splash Screen

Tags: c#, .net, splash-screen

In my application it takes some time to loan my initial screen(1-2 mins). Since it has so many controls to be filled by Database.

So I need to have a splash screen, it will load(probably with a progress bar) and stays while main form loads. Means in background I need to load main form (better with out showing)

Only main window finishes loading, it notifies to splash, the splash will go off and main will be visible.

I tried to achieve above with several way but no success.

Any one can help me ?

Comment: Doesn't it work: just create a window with progress bar before starting to load the main form?

Comment: do a quick google search, you will be surprised how many good results you get

Comment: I did Google but most of example are talking about only showing splash, not giving time to do a lengthy process to run back ground.

Answer (score 3):

look at this [Splash screen](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/prettygoodsplashscreen.aspx)

and this [Splash screen class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.windows.splashscreen.aspx)

Comment: This is for WPF, I need for standard c# app.

Answer (score 1):

```
FormSplash splash = new FormSplash();

this.BeginInvoke(
    new MethodInvoker(
        () =>
        {
            splash.Show();
        }
    )
);

// main form code here

// at end of loading code
splash.Close();
```

The above code belongs in Form_Load of the main form.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of good approaches discussed at [Show a splash screen at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743458/show-a-splash-screen-at-once/13143691) (in fact to me this and the other question appear to be duplicates).

Answer (score 0):

The best way and using the API is

```
  SplashScreen splash = new SplashScreen("splashscreen.jpg");
  splash.Show(false);
  splash.Close(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2));
  InitializeComponent();
```