# How to show a Splash Screen until a program loads Completely in Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms

How to show a splash screen until a program loads completely and then it Closes automatically and shows a main form !

Comment: Questions without code snippets demonstrating a particular programming problem are considered off-topic here.

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918158/how-do-i-show-a-loading-please-wait-message-in-winforms-for-a-long-loadi

Comment: Also Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743458/show-a-splash-screen-at-once

Comment: See Also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48916/multi-threaded-splash-screen-in-c?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

you  can create your splash on  second  thread and when your application  has started you can unload your second thread

```
public partial class SplashForm : Form
{
    public SplashForm()
   {
    InitializeComponent();
   }
   //The type of form to be displayed as the splash screen.
   private static SplashForm splashForm;

   static public void Show(string txt)
   {
       // Make sure it is only launched once.

       if (splashForm != null)
       {
           splashForm.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { splashForm.label1.Text =       txt; }));

           return;
       }

       Thread thread = new Thread((ThreadStart)delegate { ShowForm(txt); });
       thread.IsBackground = true;
       thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
       thread.Start();
   }
   static private void ShowForm(string txt)
   {
       splashForm = new SplashForm();

       splashForm.label1.Text = txt;

       Application.Run(splashForm);
   }

   //Delegate for cross thread call to close
   private delegate void CloseDelegate();
   static public void CloseForm()
   {
       splashForm.Invoke(new CloseDelegate(SplashForm.CloseFormInternal));
   }
   static private void CloseFormInternal()
   {
       splashForm.Close();
   }
```

}
hope this help