# Load .txt File in ORACLE TOAD using C# just like VB6

Tags: c#, oracle, vbscript

How to load .txt file in Oracle 
Here is the Code in VB6

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(controlFilePath, ForWriting, True)
Set l = fso.OpenTextFile(sLog, ForWriting, True)
f.WriteLine sCtlEntry
TimeDelay (10)
vParameters = "sqlldr datasource control=" & controlFilePath& " log=" & sLog
success = Shell(vParameters, vbHide)
```

how to convert it in C# 
as .txt file contains millions of record.
what will be the best procedure to Load data in Oracle?

Comment: i didn't find any solution till now i need to know the best fastest solution which does not take lots of time load such type of heavy record

Comment: Why do you believe that converting this to a C# program will make it faster? Have you done any profiling to find out where your bottleneck is? A bulk-load tool (which is what sqldr is) is normally going to yield the best performance for this scenario, but when you're looking at millions of records your bottleneck is going to be I/O or the database itself - neither of which will be improved by changing this script into a C# program.

Answer (score 0):

As I see, the process use [Oracle Loader](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_concepts.htm), this is a program of Oracle to load massive amounts of data, What you need to do is launch this app from c# with the parameters it accept, [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240171/launching-a-application-exe-from-c) Is a Q/A of stackoveerflow about launching process in c#. In the link for Oracle Loader you can see the parameters it use. And you can see and example is [this link](http://rupomcse.blogspot.com/2012/12/sql-loader-in-oracle.html).