# auto run batch file

Tags: c#, vb.net, batch-file, batch-processing

I have a batch file with some code this batch file save in d: drive main root We want to execute this batch file when We double click or open d: drive please guide us how to achieve this We are waiting your response thanks.

```
echo off
SET PROG="c:\windows\system32\DCOM.exe"
echo pause
```

Comment: A batch file is an executable file just like any other.  Google can tell you how to run an executable file in C# very effectively.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Launching a Application (.EXE) from C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240171/launching-a-application-exe-from-c)

Comment: we are not want to execute batch file in c#

Comment: no this is different question please check

Comment: When you tag something as **c#** or **vb.net** you are going to get answers about how to do it in c# or vb.net... that's kind of the purpose of tags.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to automatically run a batch file whenever you open a drive in Explorer. That would be dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily accomplish this using the [Process Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in C#:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
        Process.Start(@"The path to your batch file goes here.");
      }
   }
}
```