# How to open another program from my first in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to open a second program from my first program and still be able to work on my first program. And another thing is to close the second program from my first. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What are you talking about? About managing opened solutions in Visual Studio? Or about launching another exe file from the program?

Comment: launching another exe file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For running the program:

You need `using System.Diagnostics;`

```
Process open_exe(string path)
    {
    Process to_open;
    to_open.StartInfo.FileName = path;
    to_open.Start();
    return (to_open);
    }
```

For closing the program:

```
void close_exe(Process p, bool force = false)
    {
    if(force)
        {
        p.Kill();
        }
    else
        {
        p.CloseMainWindow();
        }
    }
```

When calling `open_exe`, it returns a `Process`, which you can use in the `close_exe` function as the argument.

Addition: on the `close_exe` function, you can either call it by:

> close_exe(process);

This will use the default value for `force` as `false`, and will not force it to close

---

> close_exe(process, true);

This will not use the default value for `force`, and use `true`, and will thus force it to close

Answer (score 0):

As to launching another exe-file see the following:
[codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4272/Using-Diagnostics-Process-to-start-an-external-app), [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240171/launching-a-application-exe-from-c)

As to closing the application I would say that the way to close the app depends on your needs.
Two ways come to my mind immediately.

- The first is to ungracefully kill the exe as a process. You can kill
  any exe either by id or it's exe-name.
- The second one is to set up a
  communication between two processes with the help of WCF for
  interprocess communication.

You can easily google about killing processes in C# as well as about setting up a communication between two processes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it just for one line (with "using System.Diagnostics")

```
 Process.Start(pathToAnotherProgramm);
```