# How to open firefox "open menu" using keyboard shortcut?

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox-addon

How to open firefox "open menu" using keyboard shortcut?
I am unable to find the keyboard shortcut on google. I want to automate the process using selenium as I want to open an installed add on.

[image]

Comment: It's Common `CTRL + O`

Comment: CTRL+O is for opening a file

Comment: F10 - nothing happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an automation task like this you maybe using the wrong technology.

Have you tried using [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) for a task like this? Then switching back to Selenium when you need to interact with the DOM?

Comment: okay...i was thinking if i can use the keyboard shortcuts..as there are number of selenium commands to execute key based operations. I will try autoit as well. will update.

Comment: @Harsh Correct, you can use the Selenium `SendKeys();` method but that relies on the version of firefox you are using to have a Key function for every step you require to install a plugin. It doesn't seem the right tool for the job.

Comment: yeah..actually i was trying this code which i googled on stackoverflow..WebElement toClear = d1.findElementByXPath("html/body/form/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/input");
                    toClear.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "a");
                    toClear.sendKeys(Keys.DELETE);
                    ..but let me try auto it also, i will update you..meanwhile if you get some info regarding this methodology and then do update me...thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi Jamie..when I have used the autoit script in .exe format, i implemented selenium using the                                          Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\pcs\\Desktop\\TEST_x64.exe");             and also following version of .exe file Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\pcs\\Desktop\\TEST.exe"); and I am getting following error :                                 Jun 04, 2015 4:24:33 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog destroyHarder
INFO: Command failed to close cleanly. Destroying forcefully (v2). org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog@

Comment: Have you tried using the `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()`? See this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240171/launching-a-application-exe-from-c

Answer (score 0):

You can reach some of the main menu's options via the hidden extended menu set which can be shown after pressing `Alt` when not in fullscreen mode.