# Button click opens different application in Windows Form Application Ms Visual Studio 2012

Tags: .net, forms, button

I have created a windows form application in VS2012. I have a button function in my form. How do I open a different application (separate project) once I click the button?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Launching a Application (.EXE) from C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240171/launching-a-application-exe-from-c)

Answer (score 0):

```
    Application.Run(new MyForm());
 should be your solution where MyForm is the form you want to open.
```