# How to get webm files resolution

Tags: c#, directshow.net, webm

I'm trying to make a c# app that reads webm files. I already managed to play the files on a panel using directshow.net and adding the vp8 and vp9 filters, however I couldn't manage to find out how to get resolution from the webm file to resize my form accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ffprobe](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html) is a C library that parses video and audio files. I have used it to parse webm files. Check out the `-show_format` option.

Comment: I don't know C#, but this stack overflow post seems to help with syntax. Basically, you want to call `ffprobe -i <filename>` and store the output in a variable. Then parse the output for the resolution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240171/launching-a-application-exe-from-c

Answer (score 0):

SpawnDev.EBML is a pure C# EBML library of mine. WebM uses the [EBML](https://github.com/ietf-wg-cellar/ebml-specification/blob/master/specification.markdown) file format. Resolution is stored in the WebM under Segment > Tracks > TrackEntry > Video > PixelWidth and PixelHeight.  The project has a win forms app, EBMLViewer, that demos the library.

GitHub: [SpawnDev.EBML](https://github.com/LostBeard/SpawnDev.EBML)
Nuget: [SpawnDev.EBML](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SpawnDev.EBML)

My library comes with WebMDocumentReader:

```cs
var fileStream = new FileStream(sourceFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
var webm = new WebMDocumentReader(fileStream);
var width = webm.VideoPixelWidth;
var height = webm.VideoPixelHeight;
```

Here is a screenshot of the EBMLViewer project in the repo. It demonstrates the library and lets you see the byte values and decoded values for elements.

[image: NuGet version]