# Building a shell to execute other apps

Tags: c#, shell

I'm not too sure how to ask this question but I'll give it my best shot.  I hope it's relevant...

Before I do though, please bare in mind that I'm a SQL Dev who only recently started coding in C#...

I've written a few Windows Forms apps for my employer but I'd like to launch all these little tools from a single shell.

I've seen something similar at my previous employer but didn't look at the source code for this as it wasn't required of me to code these types of solutions.

Also, I want to be able to deploy the apps I write without having to run them from my bin or release folder(s).  I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Pro.

Could someone please help me out?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3bb4tfd(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240171/launching-a-application-exe-from-c

Comment: This is vaguely what I'm looking for but I'll see if I can bend it to my will

Comment: Why don't you combine them into a single application? How *shell* function is different from a set of shortcuts on desktop to run either application individually?

Comment: @Sinatr - Like I said...it's hard to explain what I want to achieve.  Perhaps this will help:  I want a Windows Form to serve as a container.  Within this container, I want to be able to plug exe files into it which will launch a specific app when they're clicked.  It would be great if I can put all these exe files in a single folder and with the required references, without my source code being in the same location