# Read .Exe file Using c#

Tags: c#, file-io, io

In c# How many way to open file? Which one is best? and how to open .exe file? Sorry for silly question but i am new in c#.

```
using (StreamReader srStreamReader = new StreamReader(sString))
      {
        while ((sline = srStreamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
         {
            Console.WriteLine(sline);
         }
     }
```

I am use this code for this but am not able. so please help

Comment: Open as in load its contents into a buffer or open as in execute? - if the if the former File.ReadAllBytes() if the latter Process.Start()

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/240610/6170109).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the problem correctly

You can use like this

```
string path;
byte[] bufferArray = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
string base64EncodedString = Convert.ToBase64String(bufferArray );


bufferArray = Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedString );
File.WriteAllBytes(path, bufferArray );
```

Comment: - I have an easier solution, here:                         `using (var sw = new StreamReader(ofd.FileName, Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252")))
                        {
                            var s = sw.ReadToEnd();
                            s = s.Replace('\x0', ' '); // replace NUL bytes with spaces
                            richTextBox1.Text = s;                                                                        }`

Answer (score 0):

By open file do you mean execute it or read line by line?

If execute then probably something like this is the answer:

```
    Process.Start("C:\\");
```

Comment: yes..!! open means read..but i am not able to open .exe file using StreamReader.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you've provided, it looks like you want to be able to view the source of an `.exe`. This can't be done without using a decompiler and knowing what the application was compiled with.

If you're trying to execute the `.exe` file, then take a look at the static method [`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filePath)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(v=vs.110).aspx).

If you're trying to actually *read* the contents, you can use [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) or other similar software to decompile the application to view source. ILSpy has source available on GitHub, so you'll be able to use that to get the contents you want.