# Running an application from my program does not launch it the same way as when double clicking manually

Tags: c#, windows, executable

To launch an application from my C# program, I have tried the solutions listed in the thread at the following link : [Launching an application (.EXE) from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240171/launching-an-application-exe-from-c) .

I am facing a puzzling situation : no new window shows during the time my program runs, so I opened the processes list hoping to get more info. Here is what happens : when I double click my executable (case 1 : not using the code to execute the app), 5 different processes bearing the same name but different PIDs are raised and if I close the app, all of them shut down too so here I assume that all of these should run for my app to launch correctly; on the other hand, whenever I use the program to launch the app, only one process is initiated and no window is displayed (this is not a matter of [ProcessStartInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.windowstyle?view=netframework-4.8#System_Diagnostics_ProcessStartInfo_WindowStyle) since I made sure to change the parameters so that a new window is displayed if needed). Any idea as to why there are two different behaviors depending on whether I "double click" manually or launch through a C# instruction ? If it is an "argument matter" is there a way for me to get more intelligence about the arguments that are implicitly used when I double click (and do not provide with my script as for now) ?

Thanks !

Appendix :

C# code :

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace GradeBook
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
            start.Arguments = "";
            Directory.SetCurrentDirectory("C:\\Users\\sthg\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\sthg");
            start.FileName = "myApp.exe";
            start.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
            start.CreateNoWindow = false;
            int exitCode;

            using (Process proc = Process.Start(start))
            {
                proc.WaitForExit();
                exitCode = proc.ExitCode;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're launching from a shortcut, right click and check the exe and arguments being used.

Comment: You have to check: 1) how your link starts the app; 2) in `ProcessStartInfo` you have to set `WorkingDir`, not use `Directory.SetCurrentDirectory`!

Comment: I've tried to look for the args given by the shortcut, actually there aren't any, how can I look at how my link starts the app ?

Comment: Did you set `WorkingDir` and tried to run the exe with your app again? What happened?

Comment: Yes I set the workingdir the way you told me to : start.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\Users\\sthg\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\sthg"; But same behavior, only one instance of a process

Comment: Use the process explorer to see what actually happened when either thing was launched.

Comment: Already done (see in the post)